# Flutter pubspec.yaml - Adding forked dependency from branch - A dependency may only have one source

Tags: git, flutter, dart, github

I had to modify an [existing pub package](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire) which has multiple branches besides the main one. I needed the branch `3x_null_safety`
So I forked the repo, modified the code and pushed it to my github.

```
dependencies:
  geoflutterfire:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/[myUsername]/GeoFlutterFire
    ref: 3x_null_safety
```

Also tried this:

```
dependencies:
  geoflutterfire:
    git: git://github.com/[myUsername]/GeoFlutterFire.git
    ref: 3x_null_safety
```

In both cases I'm getting this error:

> pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentation is important.

As shown in [the `pubspec.yaml` examples for Git repositories](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages), you should use:

```yaml
dependencies:
  geoflutterfire:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/[myUsername]/GeoFlutterFire
      ref: 3x_null_safety
```

That is, `ref` should be a field of `git`, not of `geoflutterfire`.  By using the wrong indentation, `ref:` was treated as a source in addition to the `git` one.